# Delete object being pointed to

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, iteration

I have a `for` loop that I am setting an object dynamically in using a pointer.  I'd like to reuse the same pointer for the next instance but I'm worried that there is a memory leak.

```
myPointer *obj;
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    obj = new Object(i);
    obj->doSomeStuff();
}
```

Should I set obj to `NULL` at the end of the `for` statement?  `delete obj` only seems to cause severe issues in this case.

Edit: I added a reset method to the class to reset the values the private variables in order to take another pass. Seems to be working a bit better/faster.

Comment: You should describe "severe issues".  That is not a precise description.

Comment: Why do you want to allocate dynamically?  And why do you want to reuse the same pointer for the next instance?

Comment: "severe issues" were crashing and variables private variables not resetting on the next pass as a result of it.

Answer (score 5):

Anything you `new` you need to `delete` or you will leak it.

```
Object* obj;
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    obj = new Object(i);
    obj->doSomeStuff();
    delete obj;
}
```

Otherwise as soon as the next iteration comes around, you `new` another `Object`, assign that to the `obj` pointer, and the previous object is now leaked.

In this case you do not even need a pointer if you do not want to worry about managing memory yourself.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    Object obj {i};
    obj.doSomeStuff();
}  // Now obj will fall out of scope and be automatically cleaned up.
```

Comment: There are, inevitably, some exceptions.  If 'obj->doSomeStuff()' transfers ownership of 'this' to another container, thread or API callback that requires that the lifetime of the object needs to be extended beyond the function call, deleting it directly as described would be bad.

Comment: What would the context be of passing params into the object?

Comment: You mean why I wrote this line `Object obj {i};`? I am just using the `initialization_list` syntax to invoke the constructor in the same way you used `Object(i)` in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the pointer to `NULL` ensures a memory leak, as now there's no way to `delete` the allcoated object. If `delete obj` causes issues, then you need to fix those issues, otherwise you'll have memory leaks. (Unless the object somehow deletes itself.)

Answer (score 2):

To add on, `new Object(i);` creates a new **unnamed** `Object` on the **heap**, a space in memory that you as the programmer are entrusted to manage.

With `obj = new Object(i);` you are keeping a **handle** to the object by **recording its location in memory**, i.e. its address, in the pointer `obj`, which are what pointers store.

Then the code goes into the second loop and **overwrites** the recorded location in `obj` with the location of a `new Object(i)`.

Now you've lost the location of the first `Object`. Since you don't know where it is, you cannot possibly clean it up, which results in a memory leak.

As in the example by Cyber, all these messy stuff with the **heap** can be avoided by simply creating on the **stack** instead. The **stack** is memory that is managed for you. You can read more about it [here](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html)
.

Now if you insist on using pointers and allocating on the **heap**, you'll need to learn to clean up after yourself, like everyone else here has suggested.

The idea, again mentioned by Cyber, is to have a `delete` for every `new` that you have. To `delete` something, you need its location, which is why you'll need a pointer to remember its location until it is deleted.

You will also need the **correct type**, so that we can know **how big a chunk of memory** we should `delete`. Notice that your pointer is of a different **type** from the object you're trying to delete.

Also, please do not be mistaken that pointers only work with the **heap**. They work with objects on the **stack** as well.

```cpp
Object obj(10);
Object obj2(20);
Object* pointer_to_obj = &obj; //address of obj
pointer_to_obj = &obj2; //Now store the address of obj2
```

I hope I've been of help to you.

P.S. Setting `obj`, a pointer, to `NULL` or `nullptr`(C++11) basically means that the pointer is not storing the location of any object.

Answer (score 0):

Actually right thing in this case would be to delete the pointer OR you will end up with memory leak.

```
myPointer *obj;
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    obj = new Object(i);
    obj->doSomeStuff();
    delete obj;
}
```